# ManytoMany fields data

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I encountered a problem with my ManyToMany. I can add objects inside but I have troubles understanding the request to call the data. This is my model.py:

```
class Parcours(models.Model):
articleList = models.ManyToManyField('Article')
author = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)


class Article(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fileItem = models.OneToOneField('FileItem', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/static')
category = models.ForeignKey('Category',on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) #TODO
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, verbose_name="Date de Parution")
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
content = models.TextField()
adress = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True)
autorisation = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name="Autorisation des commentaires")
```

This is my views.py : 
    `@login_required
     def profil(request,id):
         Myarticle = Article.objects.filter(author=request.user)
         All = Article.objects.all()
         UserProfil=User.objects.get(id=id)
         parkour = Parcours(author=request.user)
         parkour.save()
         print(parkour.articleList.all())
         return render(request, 'blog/profil.html', locals())`

Each ManyToMany needs an author. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you specify your questions a bit more? What do you try to achieve and what is the problem? 

If you add objects in the relationship each object needs an author? Author is defined in each of the models, which could be a problem but you also define it was mandatory, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: i just can't understand how can i make request for getting data from this ManytoMany

Comment: what I need to do is that each author can have several courses.
My problem is that I manage to add the items to my Parcours(playlist), but I can not understand the request that would allow me to recover either all the Parcours or Parcours linked to the author.

Answer (score 0):

For adding and getting `articleList` of `Parcours` you can do:

```
parcours = Parcours.objects.create(...)
article = Article.objects.create(...)
parcours.articleList.add(article)

parcours.articleList.all()
<QuerySet [<Article: 1>]>
```

If you want to get all `Parcours` that one `Article` is used:

```
article.parcours_set.all()
<QuerySet [<Parcours: 1>]>
```

Comment: can you explain me your code, i've try to use it , but it's doesn't work

Comment: In my above code you need to pass params when creating objects instead of `(...)`.  Like `Parcours.objects.create(author='my_author1')` and same for `Article`.

Comment: should i change something in my Article models ? and why i need to create Article Objects ? the article are already create, in my database

Comment: It's just an example. If you provide your code snippet where you want to use it I can show how it's to be used for your case.

Comment: i can put it on Github, if you want

Comment: You can put and insert an url for file and line number.

Comment: `@login_required
def create_parkour(request):

    getParkour = request.POST.getlist('tableau[]')
    parkour = Parcours(author=request.user)
    parkour.save()
    for parcour in getParkour :
        getTheArticle = Article.objects.get(id=int(parcour))
        parkour.articleList.add(getTheArticle.id)
    return HttpResponse(request.POST)`
this is my code for add item into my Parcours

Comment: I see the code for creating Perkour and Article, but where is your code where you need to call the data?

Comment: i want it on the profile of the user
`@login_required
def profil(request,id):
    Myarticle = Article.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    All = Article.objects.all()
    UserProfil=User.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'blog/profil.html', locals())`